# How to use matrix algebra in R to create new column?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix-multiplication

I have a dataframe with multiple columns. I have another dataframe with two columns, factor and coefficient. I want to create a new column in the initial dataframe (mydata) that is the sum of multiplying each element in each row of mydata(a:e) by the coefficients (a:e) in df. The result for the first row in the newcol should be 64 (1*1 + 2*2 + 3*3 + 4*4 + 7*5). Ideally, I would be able to somehow replicate this 20+ times with different coefficients.

```
mydata <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 2:11, c = 3:12, d = 4:13, d_1 = 5:14, d_2 = 6:15, d_3 = 7:16, e = 8:17)
df <- data.frame(factor = c('a','b','c','d','e'), coefficient = 1:5)

mydata$newcol <- mydata[,c("a","b","c","d","e")] %*% df$coefficient
mydata$newcol2 <- mydata[,c("a","b","c","d_1","e")] %*% df$coefficient
```

Any advice would be helpful!

Comment: Your sample data is not reproducible and throws an error (you're missing a closing single quote and dimensions don't match). Please double-check.

Comment: Maurits, what do you mean by dimensions don't match? Just fixed the quote!

Comment: @Jenny Run your `df` code. `df <- data.frame(factor = c('a','b','c','d', 'd_1', 'd_2', 'e'), coefficient = 1:5)`

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you! Does it work now?

Comment: you have 7 columns in `mydata` and you selecting only 5 (a, b, c, d and e) and multiplying it with  corresponding `coefficient` in `df`? Is that correct ? How is 7 multiplied by 5,  shouldn't it be 7 ?

Comment: @RonakShah Ah, I see! My intent was to have more columns in mydata. Then, ideally I would be able to create new columns in which I multiplied (by matrix) but customized which columns were being multiplied. Is my question more clear now that I've changed the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sweep` here, subset `mydata` based on `factor` column in `df` and multiply it with `coefficient` for each element and then take `rowSums` to calculate the sum.

```
mydata$newcol <- rowSums(sweep(mydata[as.character(df$factor)], 2,df$coefficient, `*`))

mydata
#    a  b  c  d d_1 d_2 d_3  e newcol
#1   1  2  3  4   5   6   7  8     70
#2   2  3  4  5   6   7   8  9     85
#3   3  4  5  6   7   8   9 10    100
#4   4  5  6  7   8   9  10 11    115
#5   5  6  7  8   9  10  11 12    130
#6   6  7  8  9  10  11  12 13    145
#7   7  8  9 10  11  12  13 14    160
#8   8  9 10 11  12  13  14 15    175
#9   9 10 11 12  13  14  15 16    190
#10 10 11 12 13  14  15  16 17    205
```

Or we can also transpose `mydata` and multiply the `coefficient` and get `colSums`.

```
colSums(t(mydata[as.character(df$factor)]) *  df$coefficient)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. I'm wondering how to to customize it though to also give the correct outputs when df$factor does not correspond to the matrix I want to be multiplying.

For example, if I want to multiply the matrix of columns, a, b, c, d_1, e (instead of the column d). I'm interested in this because I want to be able to multiply the same coefficient vector by different matrices in an iterable way.

Comment: @Jenny I am not sure if I understand what you mean to say. Do you mean to have custom values to multiply to different columns. `colSums(t(mydata[c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd_1', 'e')]) *  1:5)` ? where `1:5` are the values you want to multiply.